# jQuery - Remove previous hidden inputs

Tags: jquery

the below code is generated dynamically and consists of three hidden inputs and span tag. There could be multiple of these added.

```
<input type="hidden" name="activeTime[]" value="11:30" />
<input type="hidden" name="activeVenp[]" value="10" />
<input type="hidden" name="activeArtp[]" value="20" />
<span class="tag">11:30
  <a class="tag-addon removeActive"><i class="fe fe-x"></i></a>
</span>
```

I want to be able to remove all of this code when `a.removeActive` is clicked. So far I have tried this:

```
$("#activeReadingsDisplay").on("click", ".removeActive", function(){
    $(this).parent().slice(-3).remove();
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

The parent tag (the span) does get removed, but the hidden inputs still exist. I am obviously approaching this wrong and cannot seem to rectify it.

Comment: `$(this).parent()` would be the span with class `tag`.

Answer (score 1):

Using `prevAll()`

```js
$("#activeReadingsDisplay").on("click", ".removeActive", function() {
  $(this).parent('span').prevAll('input:hidden').remove();
  $(this).parent('span').remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="activeReadingsDisplay">
  <input type="hidden" name="activeTime[]" value="11:30" />
  <input type="hidden" name="activeVenp[]" value="10" />
  <input type="hidden" name="activeArtp[]" value="20" />
  <span class="tag">11:30
    <a class="tag-addon removeActive">
      X
    </a>
  </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

With help from @User863's answer, I discovered [`prevUntil()`](https://api.jquery.com/prevUntil/), which I implemented like so:

```
$(this).parent().prevUntil('span').remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

This should remove the hidden input fields with the HTML provided:

```
function removeHiddenInput() {
    $(this).parent().prevAll('input[type=hidden]').remove();
}

$('.removeActive').on('click', removeHiddenInput);
```

Answer (score 0):

This can been accomplished by:

1. access the element at the same level of the hidden inputs using `closest()`
2. retrieve all desired preceding elements using `prevAll(<selector>)`
3. use `addBack()` to merge the previous element matches with the initial selector stack (i.e. the *.tag* element)
4. `remove()` them

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#activeReadingsDisplay').on('click', '.removeActive', function() {
    $(this).closest('.tag').prevAll('input').addBack().remove();
  });

});
```

```css
.tag {
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: .25rem;
}
.tag-addon {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="activeReadingsDisplay">
  <input type="text" name="activeTime[]" value="11:30" />
  <input type="text" name="activeVenp[]" value="10" />
  <input type="text" name="activeArtp[]" value="20" />
  <span class="tag">
    11:30
    <a class="tag-addon removeActive">
      <i class="fe fe-x">X</i>
    </a>
  </span>
</div>
```

Note: for visual purpose the example is using 'text' in place of 'hidden' inputs.  Simply change the type back and add the ':hidden' pseudo-selector to the your prevAll selector (e.g., `prevAll('input:hidden')`)